# How to listen for body click event within a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, event-handling

where should I add it to avoid rerendering and other troubles

```
     document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to events inside `useEffect` block. Remember to clean up when your component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log('click event triggered');
  }
  document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  return () => {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  };
}, []);
```