# how to add class in body tag in react js

Tags: reactjs

## Add a class like this  in react

```
 <body>

 </body>
```

## I am expected the code bellow

```
 <body className="dark" >

 </body>
```

Comment: Show your full React component please

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional statements to add or append classes like this:

```
<body className={isDarkState ? "dark" : null}>

</body>
```

Also, change the `class` to `className` as `class` is a Javascript keyword.

> class is a keyword in JavaScript, and JSX is an extension of JavaScript. That's the principal reason why React uses className instead of class. Pass a string as the className prop.

Answer (score 0):

using body as root component is not recommendable.
try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74429568